# Flutter Fire Configure Failed

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

I have tried to connect my clear flutterfire app project with FireBase. I only have a Page with helloWorld and the standard counter with a button. Debugging doesn't throw any exception.

My flutterfire doctor said everything would be okay, flutterfire --version and firebase --version worked without a problem.

When I try to run in my Flutter base directory through the Firebase CLI I get the following issues:

```
> flutterfire configure --project=provexmmobile
i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project provexmmobile.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

Through the CMD I get the following issue:

```
flutterfire configure --project=provexmmobile
⠼ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:300:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:390:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/hao/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterfire_cli-0.2.7/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
⠧ Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:610:36)
#5      runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:300:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:390:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     main (file:///C:/Users/hao/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterfire_cli-0.2.7/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Can anyone please help?

If it's neccesary, here is the main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          //
          // TRY THIS: Invoke "debug painting" (choose the "Toggle Debug Paint"
          // action in the IDE, or press "p" in the console), to see the
          // wireframe for each widget.
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ), //  47:20
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this is an issue open on github, try downgrading your flutter fire version to the previus one https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_cli/issues/180